# Physical menu button doesn't show options

Tags: java, android, menu

I am using ActionBarSherlock Tabs with Fragments in my applications:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity{}
```

I have added an Options Menu in the Action Bar. The problem is while this does show the options menu on the click of virtual button in the action bar, it doesn't do so when the physical button is pressed. I would like the options menu to be displayed when the physical menu button is pressed.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_prefs:
            Intent i = new Intent(this,ShowSettingsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, requestCode);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_faq:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, AboutApp.class));
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_contact:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, FeedbackApp.class));
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And in res/menu/options_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_dark"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always">
      <menu
          android:id="@+id/e">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_prefs"                                
            android:title="@string/menu_prefs"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_faq"                                
            android:title="@string/menu_faq"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_contact"                                
            android:title="@string/menu_contact"/>
    </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

If I remove the sub-menu, it displays the options menu on click of physical button.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry about what my first answer that was off the point)

I don't think that the `<menu>` XML element accepts android:id as an attribute. Did you tried removing it ?

Another try :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    return true; // override the useless returned value by super()
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did. Nothing happens on physical menu button press. I tried your previous solution as well. While that did display the options menu on button press, the virtual menu button disappeared from the application.

Comment: As long as I instantiated activities in tabs, the menu button displayed on both virtual and physical menu button click. But now that I've implemented Fragments, the options menu doesn't appear on physical button click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Hope this will help you.